# Write a Pythonic Remapping Function

Tags: python

I want to write a function that re-maps a number from one range to another. That is, a value of `old_min` would get mapped to `new_min`, a value of `old_max` to `new_max`, values in-between to values in-between, etc.

Is below a good way to do this? or is there already a built-in Python function available?

```
def remap(old_val, old_min, old_max, new_min, new_max):
    return (new_max - new_min)*(old_val - old_min) / (old_max - old_min) + new_min
```

Comment: There isn't a built-in function. The method you suggested looks good.

Comment: You could change the argument list to accept two tuples for `old_range` and `new_range` which would make calling the remap function more readable. 

`remap(0.5, (0, 1), (0, 100))` instead of `remap(0.5, 0, 1, 0, 100)`